# InnoDB Uncommited But Written (Using PHP With Dynamic Function Name)

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I made a PHP class which writes some data into a number of tables.
I call some PHP functions to write some "labels" (4 labels, to be more specific) into tables. Function names were varying depended on label name and table name to be written, so i saved these functions into registered array variable and i called these functions using these variabel names.

Since i used `AUTOCOMMIT=0`, i thought these functions would never write into tables if i didn't put COMMIT statement, but the fact is it writes 1 first label with no COMMIT statement (it should be no tables written at all).

I checked the tables and they were absolutely using InnoDB, and some commit/rollback tests i did using mysql console remains normal behavior (commited/rolled back normally as it should be).

Is there anything i missed here or anything wrong, or can you please give me any link/resource to go further about solving this problem?

Thank you very much.

Here i put my php code with dynamic function calls:

```
mysql_query("SET AUTOCOMMIT=0", $conn) or die(toAlert(mysql_error() . " on " . __FUNCTION__ . " line " . __LINE__ . " file " . __FILE__));
        mysql_query("START TRANSACTION", $conn) or die(toAlert(mysql_error() . " on " . __FUNCTION__ . " line " . __LINE__ . " file " . __FILE__));
        if (count($this->parentEntries) > 0) {

        foreach ($this->accounts as $label => $labelSrc) {

            echo "$label: $labelSrc\n";

            $_label = $label;
            $_companyID = $this->companyID;
            $_outletID = $this->outlet2ID;

            $_tgl = $this->tgl;
            $_bln = $this->bln;
            $_thn = $this->thn;

            $_jml = $this->parentEntries[$labelSrc]['qty'];
            $_nilai = $this->parentEntries[$labelSrc]['value'];
            $_jmlnota = 1;

            switch ($this->peopleLabel) {
                case "Supplier":
                    $_supplierID = $this->peopleID;
                    break;
                case "Customer":
                    $_customerID = $this->peopleID;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            include "RegisterPBUFunctions.php";
            foreach ($this->parentRels as $relName) {
                $doYourJob = $arrPBUFunctions[$relName](
                    $arrPBUParams[$relName][0],
                    $arrPBUParams[$relName][1],
                    $arrPBUParams[$relName][2],
                    $arrPBUParams[$relName][3],
                    $arrPBUParams[$relName][4],
                    $arrPBUParams[$relName][5],
                    $arrPBUParams[$relName][6],
                    $arrPBUParams[$relName][7],
                    $arrPBUParams[$relName][8],
                    $arrPBUParams[$relName][9],
                    $arrPBUParams[$relName][10],
                    $arrPBUParams[$relName][11],
                    $arrPBUParams[$relName][12],
                    $arrPBUParams[$relName][13]
                ) or die("error on " . __FILE__ . " line " . __LINE__);
            }
        }
    }
    //$doApply = (mysql_query("COMMIT", $conn)) or die("Failed to apply transaction");
```

Comment: Could it be that an unrelated query is being committed after this one and this is getting committed along with it?

Comment: Matt, no, i didn't any other query other than i put there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is your PHP functions/included files making new database connection? This may cause pending transactions to commit

Also, if any of your PHP functions starting a new transaction, even with AUTOCOMMIT=0, then this will force your pending transaction to commit

Comment: thanks for your reply.

i use only one connection in a single php file, any function that using this connection would list it as global (eq: global $conn, $dbName).

also, i didn't use other commit in any function. i used them in this  class (because this is my first try in a class-based transaction)